# Mind Bending LinkedList Implementation in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm currently reading through the [TypeScript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-aliases). In the Advanced Types chapter, I have having a hard time understanding one of the example, that is not very well explained.  Here it is:

```
type LinkedList<T> = T & { next: LinkedList<T> };

interface Person {
    name: string;
}

var people: LinkedList<Person>;
var s = people.name;
var s = people.next.name;
var s = people.next.next.name;
var s = people.next.next.next.name;
```

I'm am thoroughly confused by a few elements of this example.  First, what does that "&" mean in the initial type deceleration?  I've learned about using "|" to compose union types, but I don't understand that "&" means in this context and what the type you would get back is.

My second question is how would this example work in practice? How would you actually instantiate a LinkedList object and add Person objects to it?  I think there's a bunch of code implied here that is missing, but I could not get it to work.

Thank you

Comment: FWIW I think this is a bad idea. You should not combine the list metadata with the payload into the same object. This won't work if there is already a `next` field in `T`. It also prevents you from putting the same object into more than one linked list at the same time (or even twice into the same linked list).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't understand what "&" means in this context

As mentioned on [that page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#intersection-types):

> An intersection type combines multiple types into one. This allows you to add together existing types to get a single type that has all the features you need. For example, `Person & Serializable & Loggable` is a `Person` and `Serializable` and `Loggable`. That means an object of this type will have all members of all three types.

So, effectively:

```
type LinkedList<Person> = {
    name: string;
    next: LinkedList<Person>;
};
```

Given a `LinkedList<Person>`, it's clear how to prepend a new element:

```
var people: LinkedList<Person> ...;

var morePeople: LinkedList<Person> = {name: "New Name", next: people};
```

From what I can see, the only way to construct an initial element is to use a [`Partial` type](https://dmitryrogozhny.com/blog/creating-self-referencing-objects-in-typescript), as:

```
const node: Partial<LinkedList<Person>> = {
        name: "Additional Person"
};

node.next = node as LinkedList<Person>;

var people: LinkedList<Person> = node as LinkedList<Person>;
```

Any users of this would need to be aware that `node.next == node` indicates the final entry.

Comment: On the last line, I get the following error "Type 'Partial<LinkedList<Person>>' is not assignable to type 'LinkedList<Person>'"

Comment: Good catch. Necessary type assertion added.